# Finding a specific Global Smooth Function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, differential-operators

Any help with this problem would be appreciated. Thanks

Suppose $(M^3,g)$ is a smooth compact Riemannian manifold with smooth boundary and $\gamma$ is a simple smooth orientable curve in $M$. Does there exist a **global** smooth function $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $df(X)|_{\gamma} \neq 0$ along $\gamma$ and $|df|_g \neq 0 $ in $M$. ($X$ denotes the unit tangent vector on $\gamma$.)

in plain words does there exist a smooth function f whose level sets are never tangent to $\gamma$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit.** Surely $f$ has at least two critical points if $M$ is closed, so we cannot have $|df|_g\ne 0$ everywhere in that case. This arguments fails if we assume that each component of $M$ has a nonempty boundary. To the contrary, now one can assume that $f$ is generic (after a $C^1$-small perturbation, which would not destroy $df(X)|_\gamma>0$ - this definitely works if $\gamma$ is proper, e.g., connects two points on $\partial M$) and hence has only finite many critical points. Because $\dim M=3>2$, we can connect these critical points with the boundary by a family of disjoint paths that do not intersect $\gamma$. Then using an isotopy of $M\cup_{\partial M}\mathrm\partial M\times[0,\varepsilon)$, we can pull out each critical point of $f$ and find the desired function if we started with a function satisfying $df(X)|_\gamma>0$.

Together with Ben's answer, this solves your problem when $\gamma$ is a proper embedding. I am not sure if that condition is necessary. However, whenever you have two sequences $s_i$, $t_i$ with distinct limit points in $\overline{\mathbb R}=\mathbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$, such that $\gamma(s_i)$ and $\gamma(t_i)$ converge to the same point in $M$, then such a function $f$ cannot exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made an error when I was typing the question, and that is to say that the manifold has a boundary and I have edited the question. Surely now $f$ does not necessarily has to have a critical point.

Comment: Also, Your solution seems to take a specific $/gamma$ where as  I am asking whether such a function exists for any arbitrary smooth simple curve.

Comment: I just realised that the $C^1$-small perturbation that does not destroy $df(X)_\gamma>0$ might be hard to acchieve if $\gamma$ is not proper, because then $|df(X)|_{\gamma(t)}$ can become arbitrarily small. But in the case where $\gamma$ joins two points on the boundary, I don't see a problem now.

Comment: thanks for your detailed remarks.  I think now I know how to remove the critical points from the manifold, but still I would like to think more about the existence of a function such that $df(X) >0$ along $\gamma$ when say $\gamma$ is a simple geodesic connecting two points on the boundary so that counter examples such as dense curves are removed.

Comment: @Ali If $\gamma\colon[a,b]\to M$ is smooth, injective and joins two points on the boundary, then you can find a smooth, injective map $[a-\varepsilon,b+\varepsilon]\times D^2\to M\cup_{\partial M}(\partial M\times[0,\varepsilon))$ (tubular nieghbourhood). On the image, let $f$ be the first coordinate, then extend to a smooth function and continue as above.

Comment: The argument of pushing critical points outside relied on finite number of critical points. How do you know that the extension has only finitely many critical points (or even countable)

Comment: @Ali A generic smooth function is Morse, and Morse functions have isolated critical points. On a compact manifold, their number therefore has to be finite.

Answer (score 5):

$f$ will decrease or increase along $\gamma$, so $\gamma$ cannot be closed. But if $\gamma$ is embedded and not closed, then a suitable diffeomorphism will take $\gamma$ into a coordinate ball, so some $f$ exists near $\gamma$. But globally, even with boundary, we might have no function without critical points. Edit: as Sebastian Goette points out, if every component has nonempty boundary, then there are smooth functions without critical points. Still, we need to know more about this $\gamma$.

Comment: If $\gamma$ is dense, as for example on a torus, then clearly there is no such $f$.

Comment: do you think these obstacles could be dealt with by looking at specific curves. E.g $\gamma$ a geodesic connecting two points on the boundary.

Comment: It seems that the condition on $\gamma$ is not purely topological. For example, take $\gamma$ on a 2-dimensional submanifold diffeomorphic to $T^2$, spiralling toward two distinct closed curves. Then there is a function that is constant on each of the limit curves and satisfies $df(X)|_\gamma>0$. It can be extended such that $df$ is nonzero in the normal direction to $T^2$. However, if $\gamma$ converges to a closed limit curve and does not stay in a two-dimensional submanifold close to the limit curves, then the whole limit curve will be critical for any $f$ with $df(X)|_\gamma\ge 0$.